# Use lodash in Nuxt with Composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, lodash, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to use lodash with Nuxt2 Composition API (https://composition-api.nuxtjs.org/)

However, with `useContext()` I'm not able to find any global Vue prototype functions. So when I tried it by creating a module with nuxt modules. And I got the `$lodash` in `useContext()`. But when I call `$lodash.all([true, false])` it says $lodash.all is not a function.

The only trick it made the $lodash available in nuxt context was using `inject`. I'm sharing my setup.

```js
// modules/lodash/index.js

const path = require('path')

module.exports = function nuxtLodash(moduleOptions) {
  const lodashOptions = Object.assign({}, this.options.lodash, moduleOptions)

  // Register plugin
  this.addPlugin({
    src: path.resolve(__dirname, 'plugin.js'),
    ssr: false,
    fileName: 'lodash.js',
    options: {
      lodashOptions
    }
  })
}
```

```js
// modules/lodash/plugin.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueLodash from 'vue-lodash'
import lodash from 'lodash'

Vue.use(VueLodash, { name: '$_', lodash })

export default function(ctx, inject) {
  inject('lodash', lodash)
}
```

```js
// nuxt.config.js
  modules: [
    // ... other modules
    '~/modules/lodash'
  ],
```

Now, when I'm using this in my components with composition api, I'm getting an error.

```js
<script>
import {
  defineComponent,
  useContext
} from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const { $lodash } = useContext()
    console.log($lodash)
    console.log($lodash().all([true, false]))
  }
})
</script>
```

Any proper way to use this? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest idea would be importing functions you need via `import { all } from 'lodash-es` (and installing lodash-es as dependency). This way, you don't add the whole lodash library to your bundle and don't have any issues with imports.

```js
import {
  defineComponent
} from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'

import { all } from 'lodash-es'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    console.log(all([true, false]))
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggession. However, I'm getting an error with that. I removed plugin and module and added lodash-es module. But lodash import statement everywhere. Now I'm getting this error: `Must use import to load ES Module`

Comment: Some of my templates are also using `_` directly. Any way templates can use this?

Comment: Is that something related to : https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/4800

Comment: Got the actual issue: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/5033

Comment: So looks like lodash-es can't be used and back to the original question

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after a bunch of issues in the libraries and platforms it self I was able to solve it. There were multiple things which was causing issues.

1. Node 14 module issue: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/4800
2. Must use import to load ES Module: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/5033
3. Some ESM issue: https://github.com/standard-things/esm/issues/855

And after bunch of other issues, loaded lodash with babel:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-lodash

Added normal `lodash` and dev `babel-plugin-lodash` dependencies.

As nuxt has babel support inbuilt, added a plugin in the babel list:

```
 build: {
    babel: {
      plugins: ['lodash']
    }
  }
```

And then it seems like a normal _ import works!